# Limit total number of products in category with woocommerce_product_query (not per page)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to limit the TOTAL number in a product category (NOT per page products)?

More specifically, I use 'woocommerce_product_query' to automatically add all products to a specific product category with this code in function.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'specific_category' );
 
function specific_category( $q ) {
    if (is_product_category('category-name')) { // name of that specific category
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
        $q->set( 'product_cat', null );
        $product_ids = wc_get_product();
        $q->set( 'post__in', $product_ids );

    }
}
```

And now there will be 2000 products in this category, how to get/output only latest 10 products?

I'm aware this will give me a specific number of products per page:

```
$q->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
```

Which is not what I need. I tried with 'limit' :

```
$q->set( 'limit', 10 );
```

but the limit doesn't work.

And tried with post_limits too, also not working

```
function limit_number_of_products( $limit, $query ) {
    if ($query->is_product_category('category-name') ) {
        return 'LIMIT 0, 10';
    }
    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'limit_number_of_products', 10, 2 );
```

If not possible here in this query then any suggestion for limiting the total number of products in the category in another way is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: $q->set( 'nopaging' , true ); maybe ? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately, it is not working. Also, I would need pagination if later I need to change and increase the total number of products in category

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have this issue too, these two filters worked as a solution in my case:

```
add_filter('found_posts', 'foundposts_function', 10, 2);
function foundposts_function($found_posts, $query) {
    $found_posts = 10;
    return $found_posts;
}

add_filter('post_limits', 'limitpostnumber', 10, 2);
function limitpostnumber($limit) {
    return 'LIMIT 0, 10';
}
```